# Can I write LXDE panel plugins using C#?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I'd like to develop a plugin for LXPanel, the panel component for LXDE. They have instructions on how to create one [using GTK+](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_write_plugins_for_LXPanel), but I'd prefer to use C#. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone might correct me in this but I don't see how this should be possible at the moment, since you need these development libraries stated in that document, and unless the developers don't offer at least the possibility for some kind of binding as it was done with for example XFCE and python (pyxfce), I don't see this happen.

There is for example a feature request for python bindings for the LXPanel, but it has been open for 3 years and there seem to be no news about this so far.

Actually for me the decision to write panel plugins in C seems perfectly logic to me, LXDE was written in mind to run even on low-end machines, and while users can run programs written in every language, the underlying base should be as fast as possible. Even if C#, Java and Python might be more easy to handle, C seems to me the more obvious choice here.